# Seaborn sns.FacetGrid ValueError: Axes instance argument was not found in a figure

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying visualize t-SNE of MIST dataset by using searborn facetgrid, however getting error while plotting. Below is the code and the error

```html
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns 
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import manifold
%matplotlib inline
data = datasets.fetch_openml('mnist_784',
version=1,
return_X_y=True
)
pixel_values, targets = data
targets = targets.astype(int)
single_image =  pixel_values[1, :].reshape(28,28)
plt.imshow(single_image, cmap='gray')
tsne = manifold.TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=42)
transformed_data = tsne.fit_transform(pixel_values[:3000, :])
tsne_df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((transformed_data, targets[:3000])), columns=["x", "y", "targets"])
tsne_df.loc[:,"targets"] = tsne_df.targets.astype(int)
grid = sns.FacetGrid(tsne_df, hue="targets", height=8)
grid.map(plt.scatter, "x", "y").add_legend()
```

However, I get following error on running the grid.map(plt.scatter, "x", "y").add_legend()

```html
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-84d161de948f> in <module>
----> 1 grid.map(plt.scatter, "x", "y").add_legend()

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py in map(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    736 
    737             # Get the current axis
--> 738             ax = self.facet_axis(row_i, col_j)
    739 
    740             # Decide what color to plot with

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py in facet_axis(self, row_i, col_j)
    866 
    867         # Get a reference to the axes object we want, and make it active
--> 868         plt.sca(ax)
    869         return ax
    870 

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in sca(ax)
    856             m.canvas.figure.sca(ax)
    857             return
--> 858     raise ValueError("Axes instance argument was not found in a figure")
    859 
    860 

ValueError: Axes instance argument was not found in a figure
```

Comment: `grid = sns.FacetGrid(tsne_df, hue="targets", height=8)` is not correct. You most provide the row and column paramter. [seaborn.FacetGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Thanks, I just updated the line to grid = sns.FacetGrid(tsne_df,row="x", col="y", hue="targets", size=8) IT did not gave error but now it's been 4 hours the code is running and is still running.

Comment: If you have a lot of column/row combinations using FacetGrid might not work. Looks like the answer by Diziet below shows a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve with your FacetGrid.

If you want to plot the tSNE, then you should just do:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
s = ax.scatter(tsne_df['x'], tsne_df['y'], c=tsne_df['targets'], cmap='tab10', ec='w')
ax.legend(*s.legend_elements(), title="Targets")
```

[image]

A FacetGrid allows you to split that graph according to a categorical data (not a numeric data like you were trying to do). Therefore, you can do a different scatterplot for each of the target number if you wanted:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=tsne_df, col='targets', col_wrap=3, hue='targets')
g.map(plt.scatter, 'x', 'y', ec='w')
```

[image]

Comment: One strange observation: I was able to display the graph when i executed both lines in a single row.

If i execute in seperate rows it doesnot work. Any specific reason behind that?

Answer (score 1):

One strange observation: I was able to display the graph when i executed both lines in a single row.

If i execute in seperate rows it doesnot work. Any specific reason behind that?
[image]